# MKMapView - How to detect zoom vs drag event

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

How to detect zoom vs drag event on MKMapView.

I want to reload the map in case users want to drag/scroll map to new position. I don't want to reload the Map with zoom in/out event.

Comment: Robert TuanVu I updated my coding.Please check it.

Comment: I used that code before :) nothing much. it detected both drap and zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :(. really simple
 1. keep the previous zoom level.
 2. in the regionDidChangeAnimated method, get new zoom level of Map and check it with the previous level.
this is my code.

```html
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395
#define kVerySmallValue (0.000001)

- (BOOL)compare2Double:(double)first isEqualTo:(double)second {
    
    if(fabs(first - second) < kVerySmallValue)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
                                              
- (double)getZoomLevel
{
    static double maxGoogleLevels = -1.0;
    
    if (maxGoogleLevels < 0.0)
        maxGoogleLevels = log2(MKMapSizeWorld.width / 256.0);
    
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = self.mapView.bounds.size.width;
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = maxGoogleLevels - log2( zoomScale );
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
    NSLog(@"zoom: %f",zoomer);
    return zoomer;
}
                   
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    
    double newZoom = [self getZoomLevel];
    if ([self compareDouble:newZoom isEqualTo:zoomLevel]) {
        NSLog(@"Drag");
    }else{
        zoomLevel = newZoom;
        NSLog(@"Zoom");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out through the below methods of PangestureRecognizer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragMap:)];
   panGesture.delegate = self;
   [mapView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}

-(void)dragMap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
   if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
   {
      NSLog(@"The mapView Dragged");
   }
 }
```

Comment: it does not help.
regionDidChangeAnimated method fire for both zoom and drag.
I only want to catch drag event.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem.

Zoom or drag both the cases call `regionWillChangeAnimated` and `regionDidChangeAnimated` you want to differentiate between zoom and drag.

In `MapViewControllerDelegate`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // check mapView.centerCoordinate
    // if mapView.centerCoordinate is equal previousCenterCoordinate {
        // ZOOM
    // } else {
        //pinch gesture
    //}
}
```

---

**Update:**

I thought my previous example will work. But it did not. This is my second attempt.

Add a method `getZoomLevel`

```
#define MERCATOR_OFFSET 268435456
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395

- (double) getZoomLevel
{
    return 20.00 - log2(self.region.span.longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * self.bounds.size.width));
}
```

In this method, `self` is `mapView`. I have a category of `MKMapView` so it is `self` in my case.

In `MapViewControllerDelegate`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    //  zoomLevel = [mapView getZoomLevel]; // or [self getZoomLevel] in your case
    // if zoomLevel isEqual previousZoomLevel {
        // did drag
    // } else {
        // did zoom
        // previousZoomLevel = zoomLevel
    //}
}
```

Comment: mapView.centerCoordinate => alway change

Comment: @RobertTuanVu answer updated.